# InlineAutoDataAttribute but for NUnit (for TestCase and TestCaseSource)

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing, nunit, autofixture

To be succint:

```
class AutoMoqDataAttribute : AutoDataAttribute
{
    public AutoMoqDataAttribute() : base(new Fixture().Customize(new AutoMoqCustomization()))
    {
    }
}

public interface IWeapon { bool LaunchAtEarth(double probabilityOfHitting); }

public class DeathStar
{
    readonly IWeapon _weapon;

    public DeathStar(IWeapon weapon) // guard clause omitted for brevity
    {
        this._weapon = weapon;
    }

    public bool FireFromOrbit(double probabilityOfHitting)
    {
        return this._weapon.LaunchAtEarth(probabilityOfHitting);
    }
}

// Make me pass, pretty please with a cherry on the top
[Test, AutoMoqData]
[TestCase(0.1), TestCase(0.5), TestCase(1)]
public void AutoMoqData_should_fill_rest_of_arguments_that_are_not_filled_by_TestCase(
    double probabilityOfHitting,
    [Frozen] Mock<IWeapon> weapon,
    DeathStar platform)
{
    Assert.That(weapon, Is.Not.Null);
    Assert.That(platform, Is.Not.Null);
} // Ignored with error: Wrong number of parameters specified.

// Make me pass, too!
[Test, AutoMoqData]
[TestCaseSource("GetTestCases")]
public void AutoMoqData_should_fill_rest_method_arguments_that_are_not_filled_by_TestCaseSource(
    double probabilityOfHitting,
    [Frozen] Mock<IWeapon> weapon,
    DeathStar platform)
{
    Assert.That(weapon, Is.Not.Null);
    Assert.That(platform, Is.Not.Null);
} // Ignored with error: Wrong number of parameters specified.

IEnumerable<TestCaseData> GetTestCases()
{
    yield return new TestCaseData(0.1);
    yield return new TestCaseData(0.5);
    yield return new TestCaseData(1);
}
```

This seems to do the trick if I were using Xunit:
http://nikosbaxevanis.com/blog/2011/08/25/combining-data-theories-in-autofixture-dot-xunit-extension/
I cannot find anything equivalent for NUnit.

This: http://gertjvr.wordpress.com/2013/08/29/my-first-open-source-contribution/
seems to be already working in the current version of AutoFixture.NUnit2 (the AutoData attribute), but it doesn't handle the case when I want to make it take a params object[] such that the first parameters in the test method are filled using the attribute arguments and the rest are passed through to the AutoData attribute.

Can someone guide me towards the right direction ? There seems to be something missing I cannot grasp.

Comment: AutoFixture.xUnit.net and AutoFixture.NUnit2 have similar type names but they build on different object models. – It looks like you need a `TestCaseAutoDataAttribute` similar to [InlineAutoDataAttribute](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/blob/master/Src/AutoFixture.xUnit.net/InlineAutoDataAttribute.cs).

Comment: That's exactly what I want but can't find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've got it working.

Unfortunately, due to some bad design choices in NUnit's extensibility API in 2.6 (no way to override or remove any of the built-in test case providers), **I was forced to resort to some reflection to get at the internal ExtensionCollection instance in the "TestCaseProviders" class**.

**TL;DR: This should work in NUnit 2.6.x only. NUnit 3.0 is NOT compatible.**

## How to use

Just add the supplied **[AutoMoqData]** on a test already using the regular [TestCase] and [TestCaseSource] attributes. Test case parameters will be filled first and the rest of the test method arguments will be handled via AutoFixture. You may change the AutoMoqDataAttribute to use any different fixture customization (example: AutoRhinoMockCustomization) as you wish.

### How to get it working with ReSharper's test runner

If you add this to an external assembly and reference it in your test project, NUnit won't see your add-in (because it only looks in the immediate test assembly being loaded or in DLLs in an "addins" subfolder of the currently running test runner executable.

In such case, just make an empty class in the current test project and make it inherit from 
**AutoMoqDataAddIn**. Tested using ReSharper unit test runner and it sees the test cases properly and auto-generates the test case names using only the "real" test parameters.

## Show me the code!

GitHub: https://gist.github.com/rwasef1830/ab6353b43bfb6549b396

Comment: Whoops! this breaks the TestCase and TestCaseSource attributes, will fix it asap.

Comment: Fixed, forgot to properly check attribute type in the addin.

Comment: It is useful feature for Autofixture and NUnit. Could you make the pull-request to AutoFixture.NUnit2 package?

Comment: @sgnsajgon There are a few issues preventing this from being pull-request worthy... The ugly use of reflection and a weird side effect with some unit test runners (Resharper) that keep showing the tests multiple times with "ignored" every time you run it. I don't have time to be honest to work on this now. If someone wants to take it and go with it, feel free.

Comment: Does this works with nunit 2.6.3? Your gist doesn't compiles for me in nunit 2.6.3. `ExtensionsCollection`, `TestCaseParameterProvider` etc doesn't exist :( Am I missing something? Does autofixture supports this in any form now?

Comment: Add a reference to nunit.core (not just nunit.framework). I think it is in the nunit runners nuget package. Don't think autofixture added support for this.

Comment: @RaifAtef If you mean `nunit.core.interfaces` dll, yes I've added that also, no dice :( So I've implemented myself and posted it as answer below.

Answer (score 3):

<strike>OP's code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24861184/2530848) doesn't worked for me in nunit2.6.3. In fact it doesn't even compile, not sure if the nunit infrastructure has changed.</strike> It turns out that I've missed the `nunit.core.dll` reference, after adding it, it compiled. But I used my own implementation.

So I've rolled my own implementation. Implementation goes like this: We'll ask the AutoFixture for the parameters, it will give all the parameters which Test method needs, then we'll just over write the parameter values which we need.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class InlineAutoDataAttribute : AutoDataAttribute
{
    private readonly object[] values;
    public InlineAutoDataAttribute(params object[] values)
        : base(new Fixture().Customize(new AutoMoqCustomization()))
    {
        this.values = values;
    }

    public override IEnumerable<object[]> GetData(MethodInfo method)
    {
        var testCaseData = base.GetData(method);

        foreach (object[] caseValues in testCaseData)
        {
            if (values.Length > caseValues.Length)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Number of parameters provided is more than expected parameter count");
            }
            Array.Copy(values, caseValues, values.Length);

            yield return caseValues;
        }
    }
}
```

How to use:

```
[Test]
[InlineAutoData(1, 2)]
[InlineAutoData(3, 4)]
public void Whatever_Test_Name(int param1, int param2, TemplateOrder sut)
{
    //Your test here
    Assert.That(sut, Is.Not.Null);
}
```

Test will be invoked with

```
param1 = 1, param2 = 2, sut = given by auto fixture
param1 = 3, param2 = 4, sut = given by auto fixture
```

You could argue that this implementation isn't efficient, but at least that works as expected. I've contacted [Mark Seemann](https://twitter.com/sriramtwt/status/570512384030146560)(Creator of AutoFixture) also, but it seems he also couldn't help with this. So for now I can live with this.

Comment: FTR, it's not that I don't *want* to help, but that I can't easily do so. The entire NUnit integration was submitted as a pull request to AutoFixture, and since I haven't used NUnit since 2005(ish), I have little insight into how that entire ecosystem works.

Comment: @MarkSeemann Don't take me wrong. I didn't say *you didn't wanted to help*. I mean that you also couldn't help with this. Sorry it if it sound wrong. I've edited it. And thanks for the comment. I've made it to work with some naive approach. That's fine for me :)

Comment: No worries - I mostly wanted to leave the comment for people who might see this in the future, and who wouldn't have the context :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use range, random and values etc

```
[Test]
public void MyTest(
   [Values(1, 2, 3)] int x,
   [Random(-1.0, 1.0, 5)] double doubleRandom,
   [Range(0.2, 0.6, 0.2)] double doubleRange)
{
   //your tests
}
```

for more info:

- https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/writing-tests/attributes/random.html
- https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/writing-tests/attributes/range.html
- https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/writing-tests/attributes/values.html